Autocad Plugin Error eNotAllowedForThisProxy when running on Design Automation
I have an issue with Autocad API when running it from Design Automation, I am trying to copy objects from a database of a dwg file to another file and getting this error:
Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception: eNotAllowedForThisProxy
at Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.Database.WblockCloneObjects(ObjectIdCollection identifiers, ObjectId id, IdMapping mapping, DuplicateRecordCloning cloning, Boolean deferTranslation)
Here is the code I am using to copy objects
Database acExDb = new Database(false, true);
            acExDb.ReadDwgFile(dwgPath, FileOpenMode.OpenForReadAndAllShare, true, string.Empty);

            ObjectIdCollection acObjIdColl = new ObjectIdCollection();
            using (DocumentLock acLckDocCur = acDoc.LockDocument())
            {
                // Start a transaction
                using (Transaction acTrans = acExDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                {
                    BlockTable bt = acTrans.GetObject(acExDb.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
                    BlockTableRecord modelSpace = acTrans.GetObject(bt[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
                    foreach (ObjectId entityId in modelSpace)
                    {
                        Entity entity = acTrans.GetObject(entityId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Entity;
                        if (entity != null)
                        {
                            // Add the ObjectId to the collection
                            acObjIdColl.Add(entityId);
                        }
                    }

                    acTrans.Commit();
                }
            }

            Database acDbNewDoc = acDoc.Database;
            using (DocumentLock acLckDoc = acDoc.LockDocument())
            {
                // Start a transaction in the new database
                using (Transaction acTrans =
               acDbNewDoc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                {
                    // Open the Block table for read
                    BlockTable acBlkTblNewDoc = acTrans.GetObject(acDbNewDoc.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
                    BlockTableRecord acBlkTblRecNewDoc = acTrans.GetObject(
                        acBlkTblNewDoc[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
                        OpenMode.ForRead) as
                    BlockTableRecord;
                    IdMapping acIdMap = new IdMapping();
                    acExDb.WblockCloneObjects(acObjIdColl, acBlkTblRecNewDoc.ObjectId, acIdMap, DuplicateRecordCloning.Ignore, false);
                    acTrans.Commit();
                }
            }

This code is working very well when running it locally, but when running it on design automation server it gives the above error.
Any help please?
I tried the above code and working well locally only and gives the error on Design Automation server

The error suggests that you have a custom object in the drawing and Design Automation does not have the object enabler (.dbx) for this custom object. Apparently, you have it locally.
There are 2 ways out of here:

Remove the custom object from the drawing.
Create an appbundle that contains the object enabler (.dbx) and load it as part of your activity.


Can you please clarify how to implement the second option ?

The second option requires that you upload the object enabler (.dbx) for the custom object to Design Automation. Do you own this object enabler?


Anyway, once you have identified the .dbx and all of its dependencies you could create an "app bundle". For an example see this:
https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/design-automation/prepare-plugin/


Then you need to create custom activity that references this appbundle. An example is here: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/design-automation/define-activity


That's it!
